# Google Play shows no of supported devices 0 for my app

Tags: android

I am trying to publish an app on playstore but it shows no of supported devices 0. I searched for the solution but none solved my problem. I am developing using android studio. Please help me!

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="vivek.brilliance_infosoft.dustbin">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.LauncherActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/StartUpActivityTheme"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.general.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.admin.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.EditProfileActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activity.MarkerReview"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        </activity>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="Axxxxxxxx_Xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxY"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.infosoft.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1+'
}
```

Comment: Try with  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"/>

Comment: Thank you Alex, that solved my problem bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true"/>
```

with this

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false"/>
```

And I think you have to use **android.hardware.camera** rather than **android.hardware.camera2**

Comment: The false won't fix his problem. It used only by the google play to filter out the devices which doesn't have camera.

Comment: As Alex said replacing "android.hardware.camera2" with "android.hardware.camera" solved my problem, changing "required" value to false won't fix the problem. Thank for your response.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

I can't transform the comment to an answer, so adding an answer too.